# ViewBag não recebe o valor corretamente

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Estou tentando passar um valor do `Controller` para `View`, aqui é como está na View:

```
<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable" role="alert" id="alerta">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
       <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
       @Html.Raw(ViewBag.Mensagem)
       @ViewBag.Mensagem
       @Model.Message
</div>
```

E aqui é como está no controller:

```
if (cod != null && msgm != null)
{
    ViewData["Mensagem"] = "Código: " + cod + ". Erro: " + msgm;
    obj.model.Message = "Código: " + cod + ". Erro: " + msgm;
    ViewBag.Mensagem = "Código: " + cod + ". Erro: " + msgm;
    return View(obj.model);
}
```

Porém nenhum dos dois recebe os valores, sempre fica em branco, como se não tivesse recebendo nada. Não sei porque acontece, estava usando o ajax para mostrar o alert, pensei que pudesse ser isso, porém deixo sempre visível, e também ocorre o problema.

Já tentei passando por `ViewBag`, `ViewData` e até pela variável mesmo, nenhum deles recebe.

Comment: @ViewBag.Messagem não é a mesma que definiu na sua controller ViewBag.Mensagem...

Comment: @GeorgeWurthmann já tinha corrigido, mas mesmo assim não deu certo.

Comment: @marianac_costa E você pode garantir que a execução está caindo mesmo no if?

Comment: @LINQ posso sim, depurando ele cai nele.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na view você está chamando `@ViewBag.Messagem` e no Controller o valor está sendo atribuído para `ViewBag.Mensagem`.

Tenta colocar um breakpoint na chamada do ViewBag da view para ver qual o valor que está aparecendo lá.

Às vezes é preciso exibir o valor na view com o @Html.Raw:

```
@Html.Raw(ViewBag.Mensagem)
```

Comment: A sua resposta está certa e deve resolver o problema da pergunta, porém a segunda parte não está muito certeira. Só é necessário usar **`@Html.Raw`** quando o texto for um HTML que precisa ser interpretado.

Comment: Desculpa, qndo postei a pergunta, tinha colado a parte errada, mesmo corrigindo, não deu.

Comment: @marianac_costa Então atualize a pergunta com o código certo.

Comment: Já editei da nova forma.

Comment: Consegui resolver, porém utilizando ajax, por não usar mais o submit, porém essa forma funciona com submit, obrigado.